# How do I merge and zip large files on google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to merge a set of csv files and zip them in GCP.

I will be getting a folder containing a lot of `csv files` in `GCP bucket` (40 GB of data).
Once the entire data is received, I need to merge all the `csv files` together into 1 file and zip it.
Then store it to another location. I only need to do this once a month.

What is the best way in which I can achieve this?

I was planning to use the below strategy, but dont know if its a good solution

1. a **Pub/Sub** to listen to the bucket folder and invoke a **cloud
   function** from there.
2. Cloud function will call a **cloud composer** containing a **Dag**
       to do the activity

Comment: Do the CSV files arrive all in one batch or do they dribble in over the month?

Comment: What have you tried so far? "I was planning" does not sound alike as if you've tried. Therefore it is rather unclear what you are asking - while Cloud Function only have 2GB RAM. With a primitive shell script, this might be a whole lot easier.

Comment: All the files arrive at one batch. I have added a folder where I will put a .completed file. The pubsub will push a notification to a topic when that file arrives. The entire size of the files is almost 40 GB.  Since cloud function only has 2gb I can't use that.  I already have a existing dag script to zip data. So that's why I tried with cloud composer.   What I want to know is whether is any other cost effective option to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a lot easier to send the CSV files to a directory inside an GCP instance once there you can use a cron job to zip the files and finally copy it into your bucket with gsutil

If sending the files to the instance is not feasible you can download them with gsutil, zip them and upload the zip file again.

Either way, you will have to give the instance service account the proper [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) to modify the content of the bucket or give it [ACL level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) finally don't forget to give it the proper [scopes to your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances)

Comment: Is there a way I can compress the data using python in cloud composer?

Comment: Why are you thinking "Cloud Composer"? All you need is a script/program to download the files by date, zip with a zip tool and then copy to the final destination. This can be scheduled with CRON. This is a very simple task.